# iPad boot loop only when powered - brief flash loop when connected to USB - jailbreak gone awry?

Tags: battery, ipad, jailbreak

Received an iPad from a customer in an unknown state. Report was "does not power on". Device is out of warranty. It's the 1st generation iPad with a 3G chip.

Symptoms:

- when connected to power only, device turns on and shows apple logo, then shuts down, this proceeds in a loop that lasts about 4 seconds
- when connected to an Apple machine's USB port, a faint flash can be observed on the device screen every 7 seconds or so but the apple logo is never seen, device does not respond to any key presses
- when connected to power only, holding the power button will put device into recovery mode, but it shuts off when disconnected, so it can't actually be restored

If this rings a bell with anyone, please let me know what you think the issue is. My guess is that the battery is dead, but am not sure why it would not behave the same when connected to a computer USB port or the charger.I have tried multiple computers, cables and ports.

Is it possible a jailbreak gone awry would leave a device in this condition, and if so, what , if anything, can be done? I do have various Apple machines and OSs available, and PCs as well.

Comment: The reason on a PC is if the device isn't recognized and initialized then the BUS won't be put on full power for the unknown device.  Can you work through a powered hub to get it into the restore state and have that hub connected? If connected to nothing have you held power+home to get it in the restore state too?

Comment: not sure if this is the case on apple devices as well - some devices require power in order to initiate, so it wouldn't make sense for the bus to withhold power as bus powered devices would never respond in that case...I plugged it in through an apple monitor (tried LCD and thunderbolt), which should deliver power by default as they have power independently of the computer. I will try a powered hub and report.

Answer (score 1):

Jailbreaking only affects the operating system level of an iPad; it can't damage a device more than can be fixed by putting it into DFU mode and restoring it with iTunes.

In other words, it sounds like this device has a hardware problem of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either the iPad itself is faulty, or as you suspect a jailbreak has gone wrong.

Because it's a 3G iPad, when jailbreaking there's more chance of a brick (because of the sensitive baseband).

Try entering [DFU mode](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bITIiGswjFI&ei=BFEqUbGBCvKR0QXfjYCIBQ&usg=AFQjCNEQvI_QGWOP3d8fMDtMAT_ExonaiQ&bvm=bv.42768644,d.d2k) (Device Firmware Upgrade mode) and restoring that way.

If the device fails to restore this way, then it appears that the device has been permanently bricked or that the device is faulty -- either way, that's unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

the ipad has no battery to fully turn on, but it wants to, so when the battery is only like 1% it attempts to restart but it dies only while showing logo. You should try holding down at the same time home and turn off button each time you see logo, multiple times like 40 times, to accumulate enough power. Then let it turn on. when you see home screen with 2% turn off the ipad asap. then charge as usual

Answer (score 0):

Q. When connected to power only, device turns on and shows apple logo, then shuts down, this proceeds in a loop that lasts about 4 seconds
when connected to an Apple machine's USB port, a faint flash can be observed on the device screen every 7 seconds or so but the apple logo is never seen, device does not respond to any key presses
when connected to power only, holding the power button will put device into recovery mode, but it shuts off when disconnected, so it can't actually be restored.

Answer
i) Open iTunes on your computer
ii) Connect the iPad to your iTunes via USB
ii) On The iPad.. Hold the Home and power button for 10 seconds, then release the power button and continue to hold the home button until you see the following message in iTunes, that tells you that it has detected your iPad, but it needs to be restored. Follow the guide by iTunes, and you will eventually end up with your iPad reset to factory settings, and working.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.  Screen blinking while on Mac and flashing logo with wall charger.  I could get it into dfu mode with wall charger and to iTunes connect screen but it would turn off while transferring cables. Connected to mac, I held down home and power button for 20 seconds and then let off power and held home for 15-20 seconds then it would recognize iPad and get to restore in iTunes.  Got 1602 and 2005 error tho.  May work better for you.